# Unable to assign a range sub-string to an array of strings. c++

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks

So I'm unable to create a substring cut using ranges. I am making an airport program where you feed the program a txt.file and it has to divide the lines I get from it into different strings. For instance, I have the following text data:

*CL903  LONDON  41000 14.35 08906* //number of flight, destination, price, etc.

*UQ5723 SYDNEY  53090 23.20 12986*

*IC5984 TORONTO 18030 04.45 03260*

*AM608  TOKYO   41070 18.45 11315*

so the first string will be on the lines of this (variables are in Spanish):

```
numVuelo[n] = M[n].substr(0,5)
```

this line will work perfectly, but when I move to the next one (from 7 to 14), it tells me that it's out of range, even though It's between the 0 and 31st values of the length of the string.

M[n] gets all of the strings on the text, I'm using Codeblocks and a class style with header and all. I'll copy the code below...

This is my header **Vuelo.h**:

```
#ifndef VUELO_H
#define VUELO_H
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#define NUM_FLIGHTS 10

using namespace std;

class Vuelo
{
    public:
        Vuelo(int N);
        virtual ~Vuelo();

        void setM();
        void setNumVuelo(string _numVuelo, int n);
        void setDestino(string _destino, int n);
        void setPrecio(string _precio, int n);


    private:
        string M[NUM_FLIGHTS];
        string numVuelo[NUM_FLIGHTS];
        string destino[NUM_FLIGHTS+1]; //somehow "destino" doesn't work without the +1 but everything else does
        float precio[NUM_FLIGHTS];
```

Then, on another code called **Vuelo.cpp** I have the following

```
#include "Vuelo.h"

Vuelo::Vuelo(int N)
{
    M[N] = { };
    numVuelo[N] = { };
    destino[N] = { };
    precio[N] = { };
}
Vuelo::~Vuelo()
{
    //nope
}
void Vuelo::setM()
{
    int c = 1;
    string s;
    ifstream F ("flights.txt");
    if(F.is_open())
    {
        while (!F.eof())
        {
            getline(F,s);
            M[c] = s;
            cout << M[c] << endl;
            c++;
        }
        //sets all values
    for(c = 0; c < NUM_FLIGHTS; c++)
    {
        setNumVuelo(M[c],c);
        setDestino(M[c],c);
        setPrecio(M[c],c);
    }
    F.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "ERROR document wasn't found" << endl;
    }
}

void Vuelo::setNumVuelo(string _numVuelo, int n)
{
    numVuelo[n]= _numVuelo.substr(0,5); //this works
    cout << numVuelo[n] <<endl;
}

void Vuelo::setDestino(string _destino, int n)
{
    destino[n] = _destino.substr(7, 13);                              //PROBLEM HERE
    cout << destino[n] << " " << destino[n].length() << endl;
}

void Vuelo::setPrecio(string _precio, int n)
{
    string p = _precio.substr(15,19);                                 //PROBLEM HERE
    precio[n] = atof(p.c_str());
    cout << precio[n] <<endl;
}
```

And finally my **main** looks like this:

```
#include "Vuelo.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#define NUM_FLIGHTS 10

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Bienvenido, reserva tu vuelo!" << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------------" << endl;

    Vuelo* flight = new Vuelo(NUM_FLIGHTS);

    flight->setM(); 

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure that the file "flights.txt" contains at least `NUM_FLIGHTS` lines? Why don't you count it in the string loop and don't use a vector of strings? Also `(!F.eof())` is a bad practice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons

Comment: It does, flights.txt contains 10 flights, just didn't put them all in there.

Comment: I suggest to redesign your code in the real C++ way and you will forget about *somehow "destino" doesn't work without + 1*. There is no sense in fixing of the existing not reliable code.

Comment: Your Vuelo::setM() method is using a 1 based index rather than a zero based index when reading in the flight information. You initialize c to 1.

Comment: Huh!! Thanks!! also, should I use **>> data**  instead of !F.eof()? Im new to this

Comment: John that was it!!